# Is it possible to get from Tiberias to Ben Gurion airport by sheruts?

Tags: public-transport, israel

Is it possible to get from Tiberias to Ben Gurion airport by sheruts (share taxis)?

Do I need to change bus at some places? How much would it cost (approximately)?

Comment: Why do you insist on using only share taxis, and don't want to use a bus or a train?

Comment: @SIMEL , I expect sherut to be the fastest way of transportation. Do you think the train is better (faster/cheaper)?

Comment: @SIMEL On Friday evening and Saturday, there are no buses or trains, but the sheruts run all the time. A regular bus or train on the same route (if there is one) would be significantly cheaper, and may be faster if you factor in the uncertainty of the sherut's departure time.

Comment: @Gilles , good advice. I'll certainly use regular bus or train

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indirectly, yes.

There are sherut lines to Tiberias from Tel Aviv and Haifa:

1. Tel Aviv - Tiberias 5:30-19:00, every 20-60 minutes, 56 ILS. A train from Ben Gurion to Tel aviv will cost an additional 13.50 ILS.
2. Haifa - Tiberias 5:30-20:00, every 20-60 minutes, 30 ILS. A sherut to from Ben Gurion to Haifa would cost an additional 71 ILS.

**NOTE**: This is based on Ministry of Transportation information ([Hebrew site](http://he.mot.gov.il/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=524:rishayoun-kaveysherot&catid=82:2010-04-14-07-13-28&Itemid=118)), which might differ from actual practice.

Taking the train to Tel Aviv and switching to sherut will probably be the fastest and cheapest route.

Comment: actualy a train to BEIT SHAN and the a bus/taxi

Comment: @SamuelManuel, yes, it's an option. I think it's slower and more expensive, but more convenient.

Comment: The link is dead.